# Which of these 2 codes is more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, memory-efficient

I am new at learning python and programming overall and I wonder which of these 2 codes is more efficient to the next problem:

Write a program to remove the duplicates on an existing list.

The first code is the one I managed to build without using another variable which takes memory(?),
I know that building a nested loop takes alot of memory but isn't it different because I used "while" loop and it's only for deleting numbers.

1. My code:

```py
List = [5,2,9,1,7,2,2,3,9]
for item in List:
    while(List.count(item) >= 2):
        List.remove(item)
print(List)
```

2. Second code:

```py
List = [5,2,9,1,7,2,2,3,9]
New_List = []
for item in List:
    if item not in New_List:
       New_List.append(item)
print(New_List)
```

Both work fine and The question doesn't say that you can't store the data in another variable as a List, which code is more efficient overall?

Comment: Are you sure both work properly ? Removing items on a list while iterating on it is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the second one, for multiple reasons:

- The first one should never be used. It isn't safe to iterate through a list and delete items at the same time.
- Deleting an item from a list is an O(n) heavy task, because you always need to copy half the list.

Therefore, in O notation, you have the following scaling behaviours:

- first: Computation: O(n^2); Space: O(n), to be exact 2*n
- second: Computation: O(n), Space: O(n), to be exact 3*n

Comment: Would you mind to expand about iterating through a list and deleting at the same time? what makes it unsafe?

Comment: In almost every programming language this results in undefined behaviour. Iterators almost ALWAYS asume that the items don't get added/removed during iteration. 
The worst thing that can happen in python is that your iterator iterates weirdly. The worst case in other languages, like C/C++ is that the program crashes due to memory reallocation.
More info regarding python: https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/